# PhoneGap Build API Error when Posting .ZIP file Greater than 127kb

Tags: c#, phonegap-build

I wrote the C# application below to update an existing application via the PhoneGap Build API. I noticed it works when my .ZIP file is 127kb or less. As soon as it hits 128kb, I get a 500 HTTP response. Sorry, the API does not return any details on the error, only the 500 response code. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Please note the placeholders for authentication token, appId and .zip file location. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace PhoneGapBuildQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string token = "<add your token here>";
            string appId = "<add your appId here>";
            string zipFile = "<add full path to the application .zip file here>";
            var info = new FileInfo(zipFile);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/{0}?auth_token={1}", appId, token));
            request.ContentType = "application/zip";
            request.Headers["Content-disposition"] = string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", info.Name);
            request.Method = "PUT";

            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            var file = new FileStream(zipFile, FileMode.Open);
            var bytes = new byte[32768];
            int len = 0;

            while((len = file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, len);

            reqStream.Close();
            var response = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = response.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseText);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I used fiddler to capture the request from my app and cURL, compared the two and adjusted accordingly. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace PhoneGapBuildQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appId = "[your appId here]";
            string fileName = "[absolute path to .zip file here]";
            string token = "[authentication token here]";

            string boundry = "----------------------------7b053ae48e94";
            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            long totalBytes = 0;

            string txt = string.Format("--{0}{2}Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}Content-Type: application/octet-stream{2}{2}", boundry, fileInfo.Name, Environment.NewLine);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            var buffer = new byte[32768];

            bytesRead = encoding.GetBytes(txt, 0, txt.Length, buffer, 0);
            totalBytes += bytesRead;
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // read/write file contents to the stream
            var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalBytes += bytesRead;
            }

            txt = Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundry + "--" + Environment.NewLine;
            bytesRead = encoding.GetBytes(txt, 0, txt.Length, buffer, 0);
            totalBytes += bytesRead;
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            ms.Position = 0;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/{0}?auth_token={1}", appId, token));
            request.ContentLength = totalBytes;
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundry;
            var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            while ((bytesRead = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            requestStream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```